# Recreating Gibbs Sampler from R in Python getting Error

Tags: python, r, machine-learning

Below is the error I am receiving. I am fairly new to Python programming. It was an assignment to recreate the Gibbs Sampler in a different language from R so I chose Python to help familiarize myself with the language. Any help on this error is much appreciated!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-56d5c35de2b3> in <module>()
 50 x2_loc = data.drop(columns = ['y', 'Unnamed: 0'])
 51 
---> 52 gibbs_horseshoe(y_loc, x2_loc, 100)

<ipython-input-156-56d5c35de2b3> in gibbs_horseshoe(y, X, N_sims)
 33     #begin for loop
 34     for i in range(1, N_sims + 1):
---> 35         SIGMA = np.linalg.inv(XtX + np.zeros((tau_loc, p)))
 36         beta_loc = beta_out[:, i + 1] = 
np.array([np.random.normal(np.dot(SIGMA, Xty), sigma_sq_loc*SIGMA, 1)])
 37         sigma_sq_loc = sigma_sq_out[i + 1] = 1/np.random.gamma((n + p + 
1)/2, (1/2)*np.dot(np.dot(y-X, beta_loc)) + np.dot(tau_loc*beta_loc, 
beta_loc) + 1, 1)

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code is Below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def gibbs_horseshoe(y, X, N_sims):


Xt = np.transpose(X)
XtX = np.dot(Xt,X)
Xty = np.dot(Xt,y)
p = np.shape(X)[1] #Number of columns
n = np.shape(X)[0] #Number of rows
N_sims = 1

tau_out = beta_out = np.zeros((p, N_sims + 1))
sigma_sq_out = np.zeros((N_sims + 1))

tau_loc = lambda_loc = np.ones(p)
phi_loc = eta_loc = 1

diag_p = np.zeros((p, p))

beta_loc = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(XtX + np.fill_diagonal(diag_p, p)/n), Xty)
sigma_sq_loc = 1/n(np.cross(y, y) - np.cross(Xty, beta_loc))[1, 1]

tau_out[:, 1] = tau_loc
beta_out[:, 1] = beta_loc
sigma_sq_out[1] = sigma_sq_loc

#begin for loop
for i in range(1, N_sims + 1):
    SIGMA = linalg.inv(XtX + np.zeros(tau_loc, p))
    beta_loc = beta_out[:, i + 1] = np.array([np.random.normal(np.dot(SIGMA, Xty), sigma_sq_loc*SIGMA, 1)])
    sigma_sq_loc = sigma_sq_out[i + 1] = 1/np.random.gamma((n + p + 1)/2, (1/2)*np.cross(np.dot(y-X, beta_loc)) + np.cross(tau_loc*beta_loc, beta_loc) + 1, 1)
    tau_loc = tau_out[:, i + 1] = np.random.exponential(1, p)/(beta_loc^2/(2*sigma_sq_loc)+lambda_loc/2)
    lambda_loc = np.random.exponential(1, p)/(tau_loc/2+phi_loc/2)
    phi_loc = np.random.gamma((p+1)/2, sum(lambda_loc)/2+eta_loc/2, 1)
    eta_loc = np.random.exponential(phi_loc/2+1/2, 1)
#end for loop


return (beta_out, sigma_sq_out, tau_out)

filename = 'diabetes3.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
y_loc = data['y']
x2_loc = data.drop(columns = ['y', 'Unnamed: 0'])

gibbs_horseshoe(y_loc, x2_loc, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.zeros(tau_loc, p)` 
This part isn't working nor making sense.

I don't really think I should be looking up all the Gibbs sampling codes out there available for guidance.
But I think you should work from there.

Comment: Can you help see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054971/how-to-debug-for-my-gibbs-sampler-of-bayesian-regression-in-r? Thank you.